# Parse.com Query gives success even thought empty set is returned

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

So im doing a simple query for an object and I am just wondering why when I call the .find() method on query object it returns success even though its an empty array? Here is a sample of my code.

```
var HuntObject = Parse.Object.extend("HuntObject",{
    defaults: {
        title: "hunt",
        startDate: "",
        endDate: "",
        prize: "",
        players: [],
        items: []

    }
});

var huntinfo = new Parse.Query(HuntObject);
var user = Parse.User.current().get("username");
huntinfo.notEqualTo("players" , user);
huntinfo.equalTo("title", huntItem);
huntinfo.find({
   success: function(results) {
       console.log("results")
```

Console log would give me results = [] 
I suppose I could just check if results is an empty array and then go from there but I thought that is what using .find was for. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

parse.com would not throw error even if an empty set is retrieved.

A find query will always go in success method if it has been executed properly even if no results are retrieved.

You can check the error using the error code.

```
 var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
 var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
  query.equalTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
  query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
     var object = results[i];
    alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('playerName'));
  }
},
  error: function(error) {
 alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

 }});
```

So if you get an empty array perform required operations in success method only.

Comment: Ok thats what I assumed it must be. Thanks for the response

Answer (score -1):

try

```
var HuntObject = Parse.Object.extend("_HuntObject...
```